# Total RAM % from perfmon Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, memory, perfmon

I am trying to find a good way to get available RAM percentage from perfmon.  I can get Available Mbytes but I can't find any way to get the total installed memory on the server or what is in use via perfmon.  I can obviously alert on GB but each of my servers have different total RAM so not a great alert.

The way I understand % Committed Bytes is this includes page files on disk so this is not a good indicator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, [there is no default Performance Monitor counter that does this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx#XSLTsection131121120120). You will need to consider using WMI to tally the total RAM in a server, then totaling the amount of used RAM versus free RAM, storing that data as it is collected, and then presenting it in a pretty way.

However, that kind of thing has already been done for you in the form of [the basic features of most NMSs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems).

P.S. If you're extremely adventurous, you could try [writing custom perfmon counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6xtw1c12%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @WesleyDavid.  I was afraid of that.  I want to stick with perfmon.  Seems like it would be a common request so MSFT would add but guess not.  I will just have to create variables for all my servers and compute percentage that way.  Not ideal.  Thanks again for the options.

Comment: @Xaxum, Did you end up creating custom perfmon variables, or did you make the WMI calls that Wesley mentioned? What method did you find easier? I'm in exactly the same position now... I'd like to hear whatever advice you could give on this.